# Installing Laravel resulted in unable to find the socket transport ssl

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Hi I am trying to install laravel on my server.This is what I did.First I installed composer and tryed running this command in cmd:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel RestPHP
```

After running it I got this this message:

[image]

I tryed googeling about this error but could not find anything concrete regarding this error I am very new to php.

After this I tryed a more manual approach.I downloaded laravel and put it in my htdocs folder , then I tryed openning it like this:

```
http://localhost:8585/laravel/public/
```

But I got this message:

> Warning: require(E:\Projects
>   IDE\PHPStorm\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\Projects
>   IDE\PHPStorm\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'E:\Projects
>   IDE\PHPStorm\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;E:\Projects IDE\PHPStorm\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   E:\Projects IDE\PHPStorm\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php
>   on line 17

I have my htdocs route at:

> E:\Projects IDE\PHPStorm\xampp\htdocs

Both cases seem to be some for of php configuration problem , since I have 0 knowledge of that I could not find a solution.

Could someone please provided me with a step by step solution?

**UPDATE**

I managed to enable socket transparency ssl and after trying to run the command I get this:

[image]

I have also installed git but I still get the same error.What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure git is in your PATH, that would probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling php_sockets and open_ssl in your php ini

Comment: You mean php_openssl?